# Remove specific words by comparing two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists.

```
x=['billed_qty','billed_amt','sale_value']

y=['george billed_qty', 'sam billed_amt', 'ricky sale_value', 'donald billed_qty']
```

I need to eliminate the words in list y that occur in list x and want the resultant list as:

```
z=['george','sam','ricky','donald']
```

How can I  achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I hate to be *"that guy"* but you might want to look into reducing the complexity of your data structures.

Comment: @LogicalBranch Nothing wrong with being that guy who gives sage advice instead of rushing to answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

Use `regex` with `list comprehension`:

```
comp = re.compile('|'.join(x))
z = [re.sub(comp, '', i).strip() for i in y]

print(z)
['george','sam','ricky','donald']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.join` with `str.split` in list comprehension:

```
z = [' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w not in x) for s in y]
print(z)
```

Output:

```
['george', 'sam', 'ricky', 'donald']
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
print([' '.join(set(i.split()).difference(set(x))) for i in y])
```

Output:

```
['george', 'sam', 'ricky', 'donald']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it covers all your cases, but a simple solution would be this:

```
for i in x:
  for idx, k in enumerate(y):
    y[idx] = k.replace(" "+i, "")
```

For every value in `array x` replace its value in `array y` with an empty string (including the space on the left).

Answer (score 0):

At the first, `split` elements of y:

```
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    y[i] = y[i].split(' ')
```

So, y is:

```
[['george', 'billed_qty'], ['sam', 'billed_amt'], ['ricky', 'sale_value'], ['donald', 'billed_qty']]
```

Now, check existence of elements of `x` in `y`:

```
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        if x[j] in y[i][1]:
            y[i] = y[i][0]
```

`y` changes into:

```
['george', 'sam', 'ricky', 'donald']
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can solve it by using `itertools`.

Solution is as follow..

```
import itertools

z = [i.split() for i in y]

# This gives us z = [['george', 'billed_qty'], ['sam', 'billed_amt'], ['ricky', 'sale_value'], ['donald', 'billed_qty']]

w = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(z))

# This gives us w = ['george', 'billed_qty', 'sam', 'billed_amt', 'ricky', 'sale_value', 'donald', 'billed_qty']

output = [a for a in w if a not in x]

# This gives us output = ['george', 'sam', 'ricky', 'donald']
```